# SQL MIN Function in a query - 3 columns Access

Tags: sql, min

I trying to use min function but it is not working when I try to see 3 columns.
I have this table

[image: TABLE]

And using MIN() function over Field_2, I want to get this output

[image: EXPECTED OUTPUT]

My query is

```
SELECT FIELD_1, MIN(FIELD_2) FROM TABLE GROUP BY FIELD_1
```

If I add the column ID, I get all the same table.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group

Comment: Which database do u use?

Comment: Tag your RDBMS, and only **your** RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `subquery` instead

```
select * 
from table t
where field_2 = (select min(field_2) from table where field_1 = t.field_1);
```

However, you can also use `LIMIT` clause

```
select * 
from table t
where id = (select id
           from table 
           where field_1 = t.field_1
           order by field_2 asc
           LIMIT 1);
```

However, some *DBMS* ha no `LIMIT` clause such (`SQL Srver`) so, use `TOP` instead like that :

```
. . . 
where id = (select top (1) id
            from table 
            where field_1 = t.field_1
            order by field_2 asc);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want aggregation.  You want to filter the rows.  For this purpose, I often use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.field2 = (select min(t2.field2) from t t2 where t2.field_1 = t.field_1);
```

Aggregation is most appropriate when the following two conditions are true:

- The `group by` clause specifies the rows that you want.  Each combination of `group by` keys results in a single row.
- All the other columns combine values from multiple rows into a single value.

In your case, the second condition isn't true.  You want all the columns from a specific row.